# Web API URI version not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use URI versioning, however I am a little confused as to why I receive the following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:61496/api/v1/foo/create'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'foo'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

**Controller**

```
 public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IFoo _ifoo;

    public FooController(IFoo foo)
    {
        _ifoo = foo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return an instance of a Foo object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]/create")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Foo Create()
    {
        return _ifoo.Create();
    }
```

}

**WebApiConfig**

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}", //v1 specified
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Update this work but why??

```
 [Route("api/v1/foo/create")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Foo Create()
    {
        return _ifoo.Create();
    }
```

Comment: Very strange, it seems you have to hard code the name into the Route.

This seems to have fixed it.

 [Route("api/v1/foo/create")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Foo Create()
    {
        return _ifoo.Create();
    }

I will leave it open as I would like to understand, why?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the configuration shown, you are using [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) and not [asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)

Token replacements like `[controller]` and `[action]` in route templates were only added to the more recent asp.net-core version.

> For convenience, attribute routes support token replacement by enclosing a token in square-braces (`[`, `]`). The tokens `[action]`, `[area]`, and `[controller]` are replaced with the values of the action name, area name, and controller name from the action where the route is defined

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core: **Token replacement in route templates ([controller], [action], [area]**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)

this is why `[Route("api/v1/[controller]/create")]` does not work when you try to browse to `api/v1/foo/create` as the former is taken as a literal string in the version of the framework that is being used.

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)